# Gather result from different block of threads

Tags: cuda

I just started learning CUDA and I am really so confused about how to use GPU memory , the problem is that 
I need to make each block (groupe of thread in the same block ) return his own result and copy it to CPU memory.

My question is :
Can I store result of each block in the shared memeory and then copy it to global memory ?
How can I gather the result of each one ?

I will be grateful if someone can help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared memory is per block, each block has a different instance of the shared buffer, and only the threads in that block have access to it.

If there is one value per block that needs to be copied to global memory, one thread in the block has to do the copy to global memory.

For example:

```
__global__ void gather(int* output) {
    __shared__ int shared_buffer[128]; 
    .... // threads in block work in shared_buffer
         // store output value for block in shared_buffer[0]

    __syncthreads();
    if(threadIdx.x == 0) output[blockIdx.x] = shared_buffer[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank u for the answer , but in my case each block have to return an array (4 consecutive values ) that i have to copy it to global memory ,                                         the solution using output[blockIdx.x] will not work

Comment: For example `if(threadIdx.x < 4) output[4*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x] = shared_buffer[threadIdx.x]`;

Comment: So I have to store the output values of each block in shared_buffer[] , and then each block will gater the array result :output[4*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x] = shared_buffer[threadIdx.x] ?

Comment: Not necessarily, if 4 different threads have the block's output value in a register (local variable), those threads could also directly write it for example.
Writing the 4 output values to `output` will be more efficient if 4 different threads each write 1 value, and not 1 thread the 4 values. (single memory transaction).
Even better if `(threadIdx.x % 32) == (output index % 32)`. (coalesced global memory access).